# Is IN with the multiple of the same values slower?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

For example, is this noticeably slower:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [REOID] IN ( 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 5)
```

Than this:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [REOID] IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most engines would eliminate duplicates in the constant `IN` list on parsing stage.

Such a query would parse marginally slower than that with a non-duplicated list, will produce the same plan and with most real-world scenarios, you will hardly notice any difference.