# SQL DELETE is taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-profiler, azure-sql-server

I have an **Azure SQL server** (standard tier, S3) with tables. I have a specific query that takes very long time to be executed:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@ID
```

This table has 150K rows. The delete query takes +-10 minutes.

I tried to understand why. First check is how fast is locate this row in SELECT query. I run:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID=@ID
```

The result: less then 2 seconds.

I read about this issue in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901299/delete-statement-in-sql-is-very-slow). I took the selected answer and extract a check list from it. See my answers inside.

### Checklist:

- *deleting a lot of records -* 
  This query deletes exactly 1 row.
- *many indexes -* `MyTable` has: 1 PK, 1 FK, 4 indexes and nothing else. So I belive this is not the problem.
- *missing indexes on foreign keys in child tables -* My only FK has also INDEX on the other table.
- *triggers -* no triggers.
- *cascade delete (those ten parent records you are deleting could mean millions of child records getting deleted) -* I tried to delete a row that referenced in other tables. So, cascade delete shouldn't delete anything on other tables.
- Many Foreign keys to check - Not sure what it mean. I have only one FK that point to very small table (<10 rows + index).
- *Transaction log needing to grow -* How to check?
- *deadlocks and blocking -* How to check?

My guts feeling is that it somehow depends on the other tables that reference to this table (`MyTable` is FK to them). Since I have +-15 tables, I don't know how to locate the problem.

**Additional observation:** I found something interesting. If you run the delete one after another, the first call is taking a lot of time (as reported above), the second call is faster and so on. If you run this query few times, it getting really fast (<3 seconds - which is great). After few hours - it's became slow again.

### Questions:

1. What more to check?
2. Is this possible to run the `DELETE` query and profile it? Let assume that `table2` has a FK to `MyTable` and the search for row `@ID` is taking alot of time. Maybe I can have a tool that say: "99% of the execution time spend on `table2`?"
3. Any other tips will be welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Even if there are no other actual references from/to your table, if such constraints exist, perhaps SQL Server has to do more work when deleting, rather than selecting, each record in your table.

Comment: A) Check the fragmentation of your index
B) Run your Delete Statement then Run SP_Who2 active, check the CPU and IO.
C) How large are your .mdf and .ldf files

Comment: While there may be a programmatic solution to your issue, I think you may have a greater chance at finding a cause and solution to your issue, if you asked it on the [DBA StackExchange Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I had a case when I was trying to delete from a table containing ~1 million rows but it took forever. Querying the rows with select * was fast, but the delete was insanely slow. Then I realized there was a foreign key to the table from another one with 2 billion(!) rows. Of course, the FK column was not indexed. Solution: dropped the FK, deleted the rows, recreated the FK. Recreating the FK still took some time, but it was much faster.

Comment: Upload your actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question. The fact that subsequent deletes are much faster than the first suggest full scans, where data are not cached the first run.

Comment: `Many Foreign keys to check` - there are possible situations when FK number wouldn't let delete anything from table ever. `cascade delete shouldn't delete anything on other tables.` - but server **must** check and put locks. Note, server must have checked all the tables, looking at this one vie FK at once. Withing one single transaction. Even *estimated execution plan* could help discovering what is going on.

Comment: Is your table indexed on ID, meaning, does the table have any index were ID is the first field in that index? If your select statement selecting based on ID takes 2 seconds for a table with only 150k rows, it looks like you don't have a suitable index for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the problem.

In order to do that, I did:

1. Manually checked all the tables in the database and confirm that they have INDEX over FK to `MyTable`. I found 4 tables with missing indexes. Those tables was pretty small (<1K rows). Not sure how effective it was.
2. I had a SP that executed pretty many times. This SP was running a Transaction  with lock on one of the table with FK to `MyTable`. I removed the lock. Agian, not sure how effective it is since the senario I mentioned above is that row dont have actualy any FK row on other tables.

However, now it works like a charm! Execution time <1 second!